# How to override response status code when doing a complete of a Source[ByteString, _]?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

Given a route like the following:

```
get {
  complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, source)) 
  //say source is Source[ByteString, _] from the Http response of a third party API
}
```

How do I map (override) the response status code from a 3rd party API into the complete above. I know it is possible to do this using `complete(Future(HttpResponse))` but how would we achieve this using a Source?

Is there a way to use mapResponse or mapResponseEntity to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `complete` overload that takes both a code and an entity:

```scala
complete(
  StatusCodes.BlockedByParentalControls, 
  HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`, source))
```

Or construct the entire response yourself and hand that to `complete`:

```scala
complete(HttpResponse(
  StatusCodes.BlockedByParentalControls, 
  entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`, source)))
```

Comment: I don't want to set the `StatusCode` myself. It has to be passed on from the Source into the `complete`, just like it would from a `complete(Future(HttpResponse))` .

Comment: I don't think that's possible, the response needs to start with headers first before it can start consuming the stream. You'd have to pre-materialize the stream somehow and observe whatever would make you return the status code, first element or whatnot.